# Pyrogram CallBack function

Tags: python, callback, pyrogram

as per the Pyrogram library documentation, I'm trying to set the "phone_code" parameter with a callable function but I always get this error, can anyone help me?

```
from pyrogram import Client
import time

def codePhone(phone_number):
    print('numero')
    sleep (10)
    return '2154'

app = Client("my_account",phone_number='39**********',phone_code=codePhone)
with app:
    app.send_message("me", "Hi!")
```

the error:

```
Pyrogram v1.0.7, Copyright (C) 2017-2020 Dan <https://github.com/delivrance>
Licensed under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License v3 or later (LGPLv3+)

The confirmation code has been sent via SMS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Topnews/Test/tdlib/prova3.py", line 10, in <module>
    with app:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 248, in __enter__
    return self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 56, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py", line 57, in start
    await self.authorize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 327, in authorize
    signed_in = await self.sign_in(self.phone_number, sent_code.phone_code_hash, self.phone_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/methods/auth/sign_in.py", line 61, in sign_in
    r = await self.send(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/methods/advanced/send.py", line 77, in send
    r = await self.session.send(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 441, in send
    return await self._send(data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 364, in _send
    message = self.msg_factory(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/session/internals/msg_factory.py", line 37, in __call__
    len(body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/raw/core/tl_object.py", line 76, in __len__
    return len(self.write())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/raw/functions/auth/sign_in.py", line 81, in write
    data.write(String(self.phone_code))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyrogram/raw/core/primitives/string.py", line 31, in __new__
    return super().__new__(cls, value.encode())
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't think I fully understand the requirement here, but from the looks of it you need to make it work. So in that case, you need to understand what are you passing as the argument to the function.

Since the `codePhone` function takes an argument (phone_number) but in your Client class you're just sending it as callback reference which seems to be incorrect.

Also as per the documentation for the module (Pyrogram) [here](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/client) says that the `phone_code` argument needs to be string (most likely string of numbers -> '2154'). So try using that instead.

Let me know if that works for you.

**TL;DR:** Use

```py
app = Client("my_account",phone_number='39**********',phone_code='2154')
```

Comment: yes, it works but it's not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are using version 1.0.7, but [support for callback functions for parameters for Client was removed in ver. 0.16.0](https://docs.pyrogram.org/releases/v0.16.0)

> Removed support for callback functions for Client arguments like
> phone_number, phone_code, password, … in favour of a simpler and
> sequential authorization flow.

At the moment it expects that you supply `str` for `phone_code`.

Comment: ok, do you think it is possible to get around this problem?
Instead of installing version 0.15.0 :)

Comment: You can try using `partial` from functools.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "get around this problem". Supply function when it expects `str`?

Comment: @XAMES3, how do you expect that `functools.partial` will solve OP problem?

Comment: I can't figure out how to use it in my script, can you give an example?

Comment: You cannot pass function as parameter in that version. @XAMES3 has an example in their post. Just pass string.

Answer (score -2):

`phone_number` parameter in `Client` class takes a string, not a function. If you want to automate the process of phone number logins:

```py
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.errors import SessionPasswordNeeded
import os

api_id    = input('API ID: ')
api_hash  = input('API HASH: ')
phone     = input('Phone Number (with +): ')

def connect():
    try:
        client = Client(phone, api_id, api_hash)
        client.connect()
        code   = client.send_code(phone)
        try:
            signed_in = client.sign_in(phone, code.phone_code_hash, input('Verification Code: '))
            client.accept_terms_of_service(signed_in.id)
        except SessionPasswordNeeded:
            client.check_password(input('Two-Step Verification password: '))
        client.disconnect()
    except Exception as ex:
        os.remove(f'{phone}.session')
        print(f'Error !\n\t`{type(ex).__name__}`\n\t{ex}')
        return

    with client as app:
        app.send_message('me', "Hey it's YOU!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```